# Help: How to write this simple code according to the requirement?

Tags: c

Problem:
Create an algorithm for a program that simulates a police radar gun. The algorithm should read an automobile speed (in km/h) and print the message “Speeding” if the speed exceeds 59kmh. The algorithm should then also calculate the appropriate fine, $80 for 1-10kmh above the limit, $150 for 11-30kmh above the limit, $500 for 31kmh or more above the limit. Use the space below.

My solutions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int speed = 0;
    int limit = 59;

    /*Get automobile speed from user*/
    printf("Please enter the speed: ");
    scanf("%d%*c", &speed);
    /* Based on the speed, generates the corresponding fine*/
    if (speed > limit)
       {
        printf("Speeding");
        if((speed - limit) <= 10)
            printf("Fine: $80");
        else
            if((speed - limit) >= 11 & (speed - limit) <= 30)
                printf("Fine: $150");
            else
                if((speed - limit) >= 31)
                    printf("Fine: $500");
       }
    else
        printf("The automobile is not speeding");
    return (0);
}
```

The problem here is that it won't print out the message "Speeding".
Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: don't forget to put newlines '\n' in printf

Comment: Yes. It works. I am wondering the reason behind this. Any comment?

Comment: You've used the wrong operator here: `(speed - limit) >= 11 & (speed - limit) <= 30)` That should be a logical AND (`&&`) instead.

Comment: @Cody, correct, but he is lucky in this case cause this will still work.

Comment: @Muggen: Of course it will still work. Very few cases that it won't (off the top of my head, checking for a null reference in the first part) still "work", but that doesn't make it correct. Writing good code means more than "does it compile?"

Comment: @Cody, I agree. I just say that cause I mentioned the same earlier and he did not look like he cared a lot ;).

Comment: @Muggen: Ah, sure enough you did. It should have been a comment in the first place, though, as it doesn't directly answer the question. And if I only answered questions or gave advice to people who seemed like they cared, well, I wouldn't participate very much here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` is buffered when writing to stdout. Use `fflush(stdout`) after your `printf` functions, or add a new line, ie  `printf("Speeding\n");`

You can also disable buffering on the stdout stream by using `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me why is printf buffered?

Comment: Without buffering, if printf is used a lot it can slow down the execution of the program since it will most likely write to a visible console which needs screen updates, and is slow. With buffering, it can write to the stream in "bigger" chunks.